# Facebook wordpress plugin - how can i load jssdk and call FB.init without any conflicts with other facebook widgets

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin in which a user sets up his own facebook application id in the administration section and using that appid i make calls to the Facebook API in the frontend. Here are my steps: I load the jssdk asynchronously and then in window.fbAsyncInit = function() { .. } i call FB.init and FB.getLoginStatus.

My question is this: how can i do this the best way so i won't get into any conflicts with some other widgets that might be included in the same page?

In some cases, i got this message: "FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem". I tried to add FB._initialized = false; before FB.init - the message dissappeared but still the flow wasn't the right one.

Can you give me any directions? Many thanks.

Comment: If other plugins might be interfering with your’s, then you can’t even be sure _they_ initialized the SDK with your app id, maybe they used their own … that could be even more problematic, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the usage you want to do, maybe you can do your operations in an iframe you load. This would make "independant" all you do there, and still show it on the current page.